# PostgreSQL searching the query result based on defined conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a beginner and I am working on a quite big query which returns about 50k of rows.
I've spent a big number of hours trying to figure out the issue and it looks that there is a gap in my knowledge and I would be really greatful if you could help me.

In order to show you the main idea I decided to simplify and split the data. I am presenting the relevant tables here:

```
*company*
+----+----------+---------------+----------------+
| ID |   name   | classificaton | special_number |
+----+----------+---------------+----------------+
|  1 | companyX |           309 |            242 |
+----+----------+---------------+----------------+

*branch*
+----+---------------+-------+
| ID |     name      | color |
+----+---------------+-------+
|  1 | environmental | green |
|  2 | navy          | blue  |
+----+---------------+-------+

*company_branch*
+------------+-----------+
| ID_company | ID_branch |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 |         1 |
|          1 |         2 |
+------------+-----------+
```

Ok as we have all the needed data presented I need to create a query which will select all the companies along with the **main** color of the branches they are working in.
A companyX can belong to more than one branch but I need to show only the main branch which can be calculated based on the three conditions below:

```
*if classification = 309 and special_number is even then show the relevant color and go the next company (ignore the next conditions)
*if classification = 209 and special_number is even then show the relevant color and go the next company (ignore the next condition)
*else show as grey
```

I created a query like that: (I know that the *case* phrase is not correct but I am keeping it as it shows in a better way what I am trying to accomplish)

```
SELECT c.ID, c.name, b.color, c.classification, c.special_number,
CASE 
    WHEN c.classification = 309 AND c.special_number % 2 = 0  THEN b.color
    WHEN c.classification = 209 AND c.special_number % 2 = 0 THEN b.color
    ELSE 'grey'
END AS 'case'
FROM company c INNER JOIN company_branch cb ON c.ID = cb.ID_company
INNER JOIN branch b ON b.ID = cb.ID_branch
```

then I get the following result

```
*result*
+----+----------+-------+----------------+----------------+------+
| ID |   name   | color | classification | special_number | case |
+----+----------+-------+----------------+----------------+------+
|  1 | companyX | green |            309 |            242 | green|
|  1 | companyX | blue  |            309 |            242 | blue |
+----+----------+-------+----------------+----------------+------+
```

The problem is that if any company belongs to more than one branch then I always get many colors... what I would like to get is a list of companies with only one color of the main branch they are working in.

can you guys help the newbie ?

Comment: plsql is for Oracle.Are you working on Postgres or Oracle?

Comment: postgresql, I corrected the tag. Thank you for spotted that

Comment: @kondzik : Please also post your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.id) c.ID, c.name,
       COALESCE(b.color, 'grey') as color
       c.classification, c.special_number,
FROM company c LEFT JOIN
     company_branch cb
     ON c.ID = cb.ID_company LEFT JOIN
     branch b
     ON b.ID = cb.ID_branch
ORDER BY c.Id, 
         (CASE WHEN c.classification = 309 AND c.special_number % 2 = 0 THEN 1
               WHEN c.classification = 209 AND c.special_number % 2 = 0 THEN 2
               ELSE 3
          END);
```

`DISTINCT ON` is a (useful) Postgres extension that returns one row per item(s) in parentheses.  The returned row is based on the `GROUP BY`.  The first key(s) in the `ORDER BY` need to be the item(s).  The following specifies what "first" means.

I switched the joins to being outer joins, so all companies are in the result set.

Comment: Thank you Gordon you are a super star :) just to keep your valuable answer for the future reference: you meant to say ORDER BY rather than GROUP BY in your reply, right ?